# how to set the threshold of Levenstein ratio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, levenshtein-distance

I am making a system of license plate recognition, I have the ground truth of a image which it contains of multiple license plates so that I can know the ID on it but without the location inforomations.So I make a list of the IDs of predicted license plates and try to compare with the ground truth license plates to know which character do I miss.Before starting comparing, I have to sort the the predicted license plates to compare with the right ground truth.Sometimes the predicted license plate could be totally wrong if it just looks like a license plate.So I try to use levenshtein ratio to decide it is or not.
Describe the problem briefly:

```
lps_gt = ['ABC-1234', 'HK-5566']#ground truth
lps_prd = ['LABC123', '111']#prediction
for i in range(len(lps_gt)):
    for j in range(len(lps_prd)):
        ratio[i][j] = lvst.ratio(lps_gt[i], lps_prd[j])

res = np.argmax(ratio, axis = 1)
for i in range(len(lps_gt)):
    if (ratio[i][res[i]] > 0.5):
        sorted_lps_prd.append(lps_prd[res[i]])
        sorted_fmts.append(fmts[res[i]])
```

I want to find a threshold of the levenshtein ratio to get rid of something like '111'
so '111' won't be compared with 'HK-5566'
0.5  is what I use for now, but I am not sure it is adequate or not.
Since I use py-levenshtein,I try Jaro and Jaro_Winkler but both of them care about the head of the string too much.

Comment: You could consider adding an extra check on the length of the prediction, so that something that's short by say 2 characters or whatever (play around with it), in addition to already being at a high edit distance ratio, would be filtered out.

Comment: that might be a good idea since the ratio  only have the information of sum of the lengths